# How quickly does the Ultimate Meter fill up?

Tags: overwatch

The information on the [Gamepedia is very lacking regarding the Ultimate Meter](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ultimate_ability):

> Ultimate abilities are powerful abilities only available to a hero
>   once their Ultimate Meter has filled. Progress towards an Ultimate
>   persists through death. The Ultimate Meter fills by killing/dealing
>   damage to enemy heroes, though Mercy gradually fills hers through
>   healing with her Caduceus Staff, and Torbjörn's turret generates
>   Ultimate progress for him. The amount of Ultimate gained appears to
>   vary between heroes, and kills seem to grant less Ultimate than
>   dealing damage.

Nowhere does it explain how quickly the meter is gained, and what % of meter corresponds to damage.  I know that in addition to that, meter is also passively gained for all heroes, albeit very slowly. What is the rate of that passive Ultimate meter? How does damage correspond to ultimate meter %?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found the following sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1651378926) which seems to have a lot of the information you are looking for. This lists the metered amounts per damage/healing and passive over time.

It's an offshoot of the [main sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgTenq3s-YesFgb-CPI6yIPpp4K9xot7LhTBo3Tm0Pk/edit#gid=1751764739). I've posted the table below in case the page goes off line.

`Hero            50%     100%    DamagePer1%  HealingPer1% DamageAmpedPer1%
Bastion         2:30    5:00    15
D. Va (Mech)    2:10    4:20    13
D. Va (Pilot)   0:30    1:00    3
Genji           2:00    4:00    12
Hanzo           2:00    4:00    12
Junkrat         2:05    4:10    12.5
Lúcio           3:10    6:20    19           15
McCree          2:00    4:00    12
Mei             1:40    3:20    10
Mercy           1:40    3:20    10           12.5         15
Pharah          2:30    5:00    15
Reaper          2:30    5:00    15
Reinhardt       1:50    3:40    11
Roadhog         1:50    3:40    11
Soldier: 76     2:30    5:00    15
Symmetra        1:20    2:40    8
Torbjörn        2:10    4:20    13
Tracer          1:30    3:00    9
Widowmaker      1:40    3:20    10
Winston         1:50    3:40    11
Zarya           2:30    5:00    15
Zenyatta        2:45    5:30    16.5         12.5`

Comment: If you calculate seconds per 1%, there is a pattern.

Comment: What about Roadhog's and other self heals?

Comment: -1 since self heal absolutely counts to it

Comment: Self heals clearly matters. Fully healing roadhog gave me almost 20%.

Comment: This information is probably outdated; the standard charge rate was reduced a couple patches ago.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a different view of [@Declan's information](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267266/181240):

```
Hero                Points              Pts/Second          Pts/Damage          Pts/Healing         Pts/Amp
Bastion             22500               75                  15                  0                   0
D._Va_(Mech)        19500               75                  15                  0                   0
D._Va_(Pilot)       4500                75                  15                  0                   0
Genji               18000               75                  15                  0                   0
Hanzo               18000               75                  15                  0                   0
Junkrat             18750               75                  15                  0                   0
Lúcio               28500               75                  15                  19                  0
McCree              18000               75                  15                  0                   0
Mei                 15000               75                  15                  0                   0
Mercy               15000               75                  15                  12                  10
Pharah              22500               75                  15                  0                   0
Reaper              22500               75                  15                  0                   0
Reinhardt           16500               75                  15                  0                   0
Roadhog             16500               75                  15                  0                   0
Soldier:_76         22500               75                  15                  0                   0
Symmetra            12000               75                  15                  0                   0
Torbjörn            19500               75                  15                  0                   0
Tracer              13500               75                  15                  0                   0
Widowmaker          15000               75                  15                  0                   0
Winston             16500               75                  15                  0                   0
Zarya               22500               75                  15                  0                   0
Zenyatta            24750               75                  15                  19.8                0
```

I fiddled until I reached 75, which gives round numbers basically everywhere except Zenyatta's pts/healing (which is within 1% of 20, so I will propose is a rounding error in observations).

Here the total points required to get an ultimate varies.  Each hero earns 75 ultimate points/second (maybe 1 per server tick?), and 15 ultimate points per point of damage.  Heros earn a variable amount of ultimate points per point of healing or damage amped.

Of interest to this theory is what happens to D.Va's ultimate meter when D.Va manually ejects.  Is it reset to 0?  Does it stay at the same percent?  Does it increase by a factor of approx 4.33x?  If the third, that is strong evidence for the above model.

Comment: This is a really good view of the information. It gives a rough overview of which ultimate abilities Blizzard feel are the strongest, it gives a good insight into their balancing. Thanks.

Comment: @DeclanCarroll It does, but don't forget to take into account the extra points the healers get from healing. Lucio's 28,500 points charge fairly rapidly due to that, even though that's a pretty high number compared to others.

Comment: It would be interesting to have the data from the new Heroes as well as double check if the data is still up to date since it is missing Ana, Sombra, and Orisa.

Comment: @malco If you take "charge required" from http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orisa and the like, and multiply by 15, you get my values (excluding balance changes after I posted the above). The number 15 was chosen to make mercy's 2/3 and 4/5 and Lucio's 19/15 work out to integers, and also makes Zenyetta's 33/25 1% off an integer 20/15 ratio. I could have instead used 75 per point of damage and made Zenyetta 33/25 a 99/75 ratio (20/15 corresponds to 100/75). Or maybe it really is just points of damage, and you get 5 free damage/second. The real question is if the "idle" ultimate time is still 5/s.