# How do environmental kills charge the Ultimate Meter?

Tags: overwatch

One thing that isn't mentioned in [this question about Ultimate Meters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267264/how-quickly-does-the-ultimate-meter-fill-up) is how environmental kills affect the Ultimate Meter. Specifically, does the HP of the hero being killed affect how much charge is gained? Is it better to boop a Roadhog off the map than a Tracer (as far as your ult meter is concerned)?

Comment: How does the question marked as duplicate answer the OP? The duplicate question doesn't mention environmental kills, nor does the spreadsheet linked.

Comment: @RowanFreeman I agree. I would appreciate it if one of the individuals who voted to close this question would clarify why this is a duplicate.

Comment: It would be great if people would simply think before closing questions. And, no offense to anyone, if you do not play the game or don't know what the question is about, please do not close questions.

Comment: @YUNOWORK That's not how SE works, and you'll never get it to.  People are trusted with the close votes for a reason.

Comment: @Frank Well some people appear to abuse this then. Because I do not see ANY reason for this question to be closed. If i read through the question posted here and linked question, they ask something different. So to me, this looks like people do not pay enough attention on reviewing close votes.

Comment: @YUNOWORK They may, or they may not.  If a question sounds similiar enough, chances are good it's going to get closed.  But, just as easily, it can get reopened.  That's the system working as intended.  Stripping close votes from users because they don't play the game means it'd be insanely easy to just pick an almost unused tag for your question, and then it'd never get closed.

Comment: It's not that it sounds similar, it's that **the scope of this question is entirely enclosed by the other question**, which makes this a duplicate.  If the accepted answer of that question overlooks the aspect asked about in this question, the asker should leave a comment or start a bounty, not create a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear as though the amount of ultimate charge is granted based on the current health of the target when the kill is registered by the death-zone at the bottom of the pit.

[Test case 1](https://gfycat.com/ThirstyWeepyBoa): Winston (500HP) Environmental

[Test case 2](https://gfycat.com/EsteemedEnormousAfghanhound): Winston (~240HP) Damage+Environmental

[Test case 3](https://gfycat.com/FeminineUnfinishedBadger): Winston (500HP) Full Damage

[Test case 4](https://gfycat.com/SpiffyBlushingGoat): Winston Primal Rage (1000HP) Environmental

[Test case 5](https://gfycat.com/UntriedAnchoredHermitcrab): Tracer (150HP) Environmental

[Test case 6](https://gfycat.com/SimpleCandidCardinal): Tracer (120HP) Punch+Suicide

We can see from these clips that, negating the over time ultimate gain, the amount of charge gained is consistent with the total damage dealt, not including any measure of overkill.

For reference: For every 15 points of damage dealt by or as a result of Pharah's actions, 1% ultimate charge is granted. This means 33.3% charge for Winston, 10% for Tracer (consistent with what we see above).

Comment: That would seem right since ultimates charge based on damage/healing done and an environmental kill counts as full damage done, at least when it comes to "on fire" points.

Comment: It would seem as though I was backwards- it's the current HP of the hero killed, not their max HP pool.

Comment: @KizTrap This is a phenomenal answer. Thanks for putting in the time and doing the SCIENCE!

Comment: Thanks :) Lurked on SE for so long, figured it was time to contribute

Comment: I was playing as Lucio the other day and an opposing Roadhog hooked me into a pit. I managed to wall ride for a bit but ultimately died. I think my death counted as a suicide since the killcam followed me instead of the Roadhog, so does that mean he didn't get any ult? Would this also work for Genji/Hanzo, etc.?

Comment: @txteclipse Did the kill feed show just your name, or both? If it was just your name then he would not have received any ult power. See Test case 6- Your wall riding would have overridden his last action to cause you to fall, so your cause of death would have been your own doing.