# Does Reinhardt gain ultimate quicker when blocking opponents?

Tags: overwatch

I saw a youtube video where Reinhardt does nothing and somehow his ultimate goes up quickly. Once it's up he kills 3 enemies at once.

I forgot the URL but here is another one.

I wonder why the ultimate goes up quickly?

Maybe because he blocks a lot? His shield gets destroyed a lot of times.

Answer (score 10):

**No**. Reinhardt does not gain ultimate charge for blocking damage. He does, however, gain lots of ultimate charge for dealing damage. For every 11 points of damage he deals, he gains 1% ultimate, according to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267266/20306). This means that if a charge hits, that's up to 27% ultimate charge right there, and 6% for every hammer swing.

Comment: Since Firestrike can pass through and hit multiple enemies, that is another way he can very quickly build ultimate charge.